# NoneType Error with Function

Tags: python, function, nonetype

first, sorry for my bad english.
I have a problem, my function which return me a NoneType Error when she is executed more than 2 time

```py
def random(k, position, impossible):
    """Permet de générer des case où il n'y a pas encore de navires placé
    et qui soit possible (éviter que le bateau soit sur deux lignes),
    l'argument k correspond au navire en cours de placement
    """
    global cases_occupées_bot
    case = randint(0,99)
    print("Salut !", k, position, case, impossible)
    if k == 0: #porte-avion (5 cases)
        if (position == 0 and 
                len(set((case, case)).intersection(set(impossible))) == 0 and
                len(set((case, case+1, case+2, case+3, case+4)).intersection(
                    set(cases_occupées_bot))) == 0):
            cases_occupées_bot.extend([case, case+1, case+2, case+3, case+4])
            return case
        elif (position == 1 and
                len(set((case, case)).intersection(set(impossible))) == 0 and
                len(set((case, case+10, case+20, case+30,case+40)).intersection(
                    set(cases_occupées_bot))) == 0):
            cases_occupées_bot.extend([case, case+10, case+20, case+30, case+40])
            return case
        else:
            random(k, position, impossible)
```

For test this function I use:

```
random(0,0,[9,19,29,39,49,59,69,79,89,99,8,18,28,38,48,58,68,78,88,98,7,17,27,37,47,57,67,77,87,97,6,16,26,36,46,56,66,76,86,96])
```

I would like to know where that come from, thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the result of the recursive call in the last line.

```
return random(k,position,impossible)
```

Comment: But as far as I can see he is not changing the `k`,`position` and `impossible` before this line so this would cause an infinite recursion (or at least until the stack is full) Or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how I could miss that x.x